# Как сделать чтобы эффект при ховере был на каждый блок отдельно, а не на все сразу

Tags: jquery

Как сделать чтобы эффект при ховере был на каждый блок отдельно, а не на все сразу?

```js
$(function() {
  $(".my_job").hover(function() {
      $(".imgg").stop().animate({
        opacity: 1.0
      }, "fast");
    },
    function() {
      $(".imgg").stop().animate({
        opacity: 0.41
      }, "fast");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my_job">
  <div class="my_job__img">
    <img src="https://www.artleo.com/mini/201211/36312.jpg" class="imgg">
  </div>
  <div class="my_job_desc">
    <a href="#" class="my_joba">sedona.com</a>
    <p>Сайт города Седона в штате Аризона</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.imgg {
  transition: opacity .3s;
  opacity: .41;
}

.my_job:hover .imgg {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Вот и все волшебство, и не нужно прибегать к jQuery.

Comment: Спасибо большое)

Comment: `transition` уже давно можно писать без префиксов.

Answer (score 0):

У вас стоит селекто `$(".my_job")` который выбирает как раз весь блок. Если я правильно вас понял, то вам нужны дочерние элементы по отдельности. Для этого измените селектор, напирмер так `$(".my_job div")`. В это случае будут выбираться все блоки **div** внутри вашего блока.

Ну и собственно возможно вам особенно jquery здесь и не нужен - и можно обойтись и простым CSS.